# python - Executing transform function on parameter dict when creating new transformdict

Tags: python, dictionary

I've read about this cool new dictionary type, the [transformdict](http://il.pycon.org/2016/static/sessions/raymond-hettinger.pdf)

I want to use it in my project, by initializing a new transform dict with regular dict:

```
tran_d = TransformDict(str.lower, {'A':1, 'B':2})
```

which succeeds but when I run this:

```
tran_d.keys()
```

I get:

```
['A', 'B']
```

How would you suggest to execute the transform function on the parameter (regular) dict when creating the new transform dict?
Just to be clear I want the following:

```
tran_d.keys() == ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: But that's simply not the point of the `transform_dict`. You can always cast it to lowercase manually though: `map(str.lower, tran_d.keys())`. It would also be helpful (if you want a workaround) if you included the actual implementation (or module) for `TransformDict`. :)

Comment: Note that this dict was suggested as PEP 455, and **was rejected**.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @MSeifert I see your point, guess that I need to do the transformation by myself using transform_func. You can look at the source code at : https://github.com/fluentpython/example-code/blob/master/03-dict-set/transformdict.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already said it in the comments but it's important to realize that this is not what `TransformDict` is meant to do. Therefore you could subclass it with a custom implementation for `keys`:

```
class MyTransformDict(TransformDict):
    def keys(self):
        return map(self.transform_func, super().keys())
```

Depending on your Python version you probably need to use `list()` around the `map` (Python 3) or provide arguments for `super`: `super(TransformDict, self)` (Python 2). But it should illustrate the principle.

As @Rawing pointed out in the comments there will be more methods that don't work as expected, i.e. `__iter__`, `items` and probably also `__repr__`.

Comment: Depending on how `TransformDict` is implemented (I haven't seen its source code) you may also want to override `__iter__` to get the same behavior when iterating over the dict.

Comment: @Rawing You're correct. The question specifically asked for `keys` so I provided just a solution for that. But I added a note about methods that could behave unexpectedly.

Comment: A link to the source code: https://github.com/fluentpython/example-code/blob/master/03-dict-set/transformdict.py

Answer (score 2):

Per the implementation I have seen, the transformation function can be achieved through a property named `transform_func`, so

```python
list(map(tran_d.transform_func, tran_d.keys()))
```

should do.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother using TransformDict. It has been proposed as [PEP 455](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0455/) and been **rejected**. This means it won't be a built-in feature, so you'd have to manually implement it on your own or use some library that does it.

The BDFL delegate's conclusions about the PEP can be found [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2015-May/140003.html). The stripped down version is:

1. It is less readable than converting keys before usage.
2. It breaks in strange ways that sometimes even emit wrong errors.
3. It introduces unneeded complexity, since using plain dicts avoids above problems.

Comment: Eventually I did not use it :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Ronan-Paixão answer

1. TransformDict was a hypergeneralization which sprang up out of wanting case-folding keys, but with no rigorous research into what real world users might need the generalization for --- meaning the user expectations of what it should do were not well thought through, as the original question illustrates.
2. A recommendation is to implement your own dictionary subclass, to fit your own use case, as other answers have suggested.

So rather than suggesting "do not use TransformDict" I would suggest, "build your own, but give your class a better more descriptive name", then you'll know what it does, will have it quarantined, and not encourage bad stuff in the repos.

A good reference in addition to the [PEP 455](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0455/) is Hettinger's presentation: http://il.pycon.org/2016/static/sessions/raymond-hettinger.pdf